# Round decimal - If 1 then no decimal, if 0.01 then 2 decimal

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

How can i truncate not with casual number like 1, 2, 3 but directly with decimal syntax?

For example:

- I have 4 and decimal to 1 so truncate to 4.
- I have 1.5 and decimal to 1 so truncate to 1.
- I have 1.5689 and decimal 0.01 so truncate to 1.56.
- I have 1.7954 and decimal 0.001 so truncate to 1.795.

I don't know if such a function exist, but i imagine something like this:
`round(1.5689, 0.01)` -> `1.56`

I don't even know how we can call that lol ...

Comment: Use the fact that `-log10(0.01) = 2`?

Comment: I will try with it, could be a nice solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach to solve the above would be to find out how many decimals are after the decimal separator `.`. Then, if you know the number of those decimals, you can easily round your input number. Below is an example:

```
def truncate(number, decimal):
    decPart = str(decimal).split('.')
    p = len(decPart[1]) if len(decPart) > 1 else 1
    return round(number, p) if p > 1 else int(number)

print(truncate(4,1))
print(truncate(1.5,1))
print(truncate(1.5689,0.01))
print(truncate(1.7954,0.001))
```

Output:

```
4
1
1.57
1.795
```

I noticed that your round function floors the number. If this is the case, you can simply parse your number as string, round it to the number of decimals you want and then convert it back to number.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great application for the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module, especially [`decimal.Decimal.quantize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

```
import decimal

pairs = [
    ('4', '1'),
    ('1.5', '1'),
    ('1.5689', '0.01'),
    ('1.7954', '0.001')
    ]

for n, d in pairs:
    n, d = map(decimal.Decimal, (n, d))  # Convert strings to decimal number type
    result = n.quantize(d, decimal.ROUND_DOWN)  # Adjust length of mantissa
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
4
1
1.56
1.795
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also do, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231848/8565438) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193521/8565438):

```
import numpy as np
result = np.round(number, max(str(formattocopy)[::-1].find('.'),0))
```

Results, for `number` and `formattocopy` values:

```
number=1.234
formattocopy=1.2
```

Result: `1.2`

```
number=1.234
formattocopy=1.234
```

Result: `1.234`

Answer (score 0):

Let's use maths instead of programming!

We know that `round(x, n)`  rounds `x` to `n` decimal places. What you want is to pass `10**n` to your new function instead of `n`. So,

```
def round_new(x, n):
    return round(x, int(-math.log10(n))
```

This should give you what you want without the need for any string search / split operations.