# Python format float with three dots is possible?

Tags: python, floating-point, format, precision, prompt

I'm trying to format a float like

`10 / 3 = Quotient: 3.3333...`

`42 / 10 = Quotient: 4.2`

i want to add three dots when there are more than 4 decimal places

for the moment i have that format

`print("{:{width}}{:.5g}".format("Quotient:", a / b, width=width))`

result of this format :

`10 / 3 = Quotient: 3.3333`

`42 / 10 = Quotient: 4.2`

how can i do that with `format()` or another function in py standard lib ?

Comment: You could write your own function to do that.

Comment: How would you want 1.999999 to be formatted?

Comment: Im a bit confused. so float larger then 5, then why does 3.33 have a `...` at the end?

Comment: @rv.kvetch: I assumed that meant 5 *decimal places*.

Comment: @ScottHunter `1.9999...` when there are more than 4 decimal places i want to put three dot . i just want to see if there is a solution with the function `format()` or another python function

Comment: @rv.kvetch when there are more than 4 decimal places yes . i will edit my post to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper function such as `print_float` to format the float and print it, using a "reverse and find" approach as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231848/10237506):

```py
def print_float(f: float) -> None:
    float_str = str(f)
    num_decimal_places = float_str[::-1].find('.')
    if num_decimal_places > 4:
        print(float_str[:-num_decimal_places + 4], '...', sep='')
    else:
        print(float_str)
```

Results:

```
print_float(12345)     # 12345
print_float(10 / 3)    # 3.3333...
print_float(42 / 10)   # 4.2
print_float(1.999999)  # 1.9999...
```

Finally, here's a (potentially) more efficient solution, which doesn't involve doing `[::-1]` to reverse the string in place. Note that it uses `len()` in place of a string reversal, which should be an `O(1)` operation in any case.

```py
def print_float(f: float, max_decimal_places=4) -> None:
    float_str = str(f)
    len_float = len(float_str)
    idx_after_point = float_str.find('.') + 1

    if len_float - idx_after_point > max_decimal_places and idx_after_point:
        print(float_str[:idx_after_point + max_decimal_places] + '...')
    else:
        print(float_str)
```